# Express doesnt send the end response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

Im having nodeJS app with express **4.13.0**,
when I run requests from postman the process has invoked but I dont get status successful (200)or any status ,
I see that the code was invoked (I got the console message)

```
            console.log("Project replaced successfully ");
            res.end("Replaced successfully ", 200);
```

I try even with just

`res.end(200)` and I still see that the postman is processing, what could be the reason?

Comment: Please provide the postman code.

Comment: @JasonLivesay - Hi But which code do you want ? in the postman I just send the url put in the header contentType = application/zip  and  upload file (in binary)...

Comment: All postman code and response processing, this may contain the problem.

Comment: @JasonLivesay Btw I try with advanced rest client and I got the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.end), `res.end()` doesn't accept a status code and you should not use it if you send back data, use `res.send()` instead. By default, the status code is 200, if you need a different one, write something like this `res.status(404).send('hello')`.

Comment: Thanks I've try it now and it doesnt work any other idea what it can be?

Comment: The code between the `console.log` and `res.send()` must be blocking. Try commenting everything except the  `res.send``and do a test, it should work. Then you'll have to debug the code you commented.